# How to log "Attempted to read or write protected memory" VB crash?

Tags: vb.net

“Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.”

I find this happens if I run a particular piece of code on a timer that executes every 50 ms.  The program crashes, but the ApplicationEvents.vb Unhandled Exception event doesn’t seem to be able to capture this happening.  I’ve read some about this on the web, but can’t seem to figure out how to capture and log when this happens.  I’ve tried a Try/Catch around the section of code, but that doesn’t seem to help either.

At this point, I’m going to assume that this particular error is a unique exception, and that I have no way of logging it from an application level since it appears that the fatal error immediately aborts the application code.

I currently use the Trace.WriteLine command throughout my project to log button clicks and other events.  I can log other exceptions to this log file, but this particular exception seems to be, well, an exception.

I’m not concerned with the source of the error as much as I’m trying to develop a way to catch the error at runtime so I can have some history in the log file that the error occurred.

Is there a way to log this type of error?

Comment: what happens if you extend time to 1 sec

Comment: The code seems to run fine when it's ran every 2 seconds, but I'm more interested in finding out how to log this type of error.

Comment: It is a "corrupted state exception", the worst kind a heart attack your program can suffer from.  The odds that you can still run after your heart gave out are always low, only an ambulance and intensive care will do.  The .NET framework pulls up that vehicle and carries off your program as fast as it can.  If you have a medical degree then you'd know about HandleProcessCorruptedStateExceptionAttribute, in the wrong hands the patient will die.  Apply your Hippocratic oath and do no harm.  Fix the real problem.

Comment: @Hans Passant: No "medical degree" here.  I appreciate you taking the time to post this and for your creative analogy.  I'm pretty sure I know what  is causing the issue, so I'm going to comment out this bit of code that I believe is no longer needed.  However, I was hoping that I could log this type of error if it was to happen in the future for things that I didn't catch during development.  It looks like if I want to be able to do this, I'll need contact a PhD for help.

Comment: You got the medical terms, all you can do wrong is not consult doctor google.